# Tensorflow failure with Python Anaconda 3.7.1

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I installed Anaconda Anaconda3-2018-12 (Python 3.7.1) ([this](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe) version).

Then I opened the "Anaconda prompt", and did `pip install keras` and `pip install tensorflow`. The installation succeeded but then when doing:

```
import keras
```

or

```
import tensorflow
```

I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
>   ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 980, in _find_and_load
>   SystemError:  returned a result   with an error set
>   ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
>   ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
>   2019-02-15 18:33:05.953996: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675]
>   Check  failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr

**What could be the problem?**

Comment: An old numpy version, or the numpy version for 3.7 is buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this solved it:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```